# nfs-kernel-server keeps failing in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nfs, share

I'm trying to create NFS share in Ubuntu 14.04 strictly following this tutorial: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo.

```
root@srv:~# service nfs-kernel-server start
 * Exporting directories for NFS kernel daemon...  [ OK ]
 * Starting NFS kernel daemon  [fail]
```

In syslog can see the following:

```
Feb  5 14:22:53 srv kernel: [37884.636698] nfsd: last server has exited, flushing export cache
Feb  5 14:22:54 srv kernel: [37885.684132] NFSD: Using /var/lib/nfs/v4recovery as the NFSv4 state recovery directory
Feb  5 14:22:54 srv kernel: [37885.684146] NFSD: starting 90-second grace period (net ffffffff81cd3700)
Feb  5 14:22:54 srv rpc.mountd[14901]: mountd: could not create listeners
```

How to find the cause and succesfully run NFS server?